# echo or sed out of a ks-file to generate a mysql_secure script

Tags: bash, sed, systemd, kickstart

i will create a KS File (Kickstart for automated OS installation).
i install mariadb with the ks file. 
But it seems a problem to execute the mysql_secure script.

My idea is to generate a script in the ks-file which will perform the same steps like the mysql_secure script and then create a systemd.service to start this script.

But now i got many problems with the single and double quotes if i echo my script like this:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
FILE=/root/mysqlsecure

if [ -f $FILE ];
then
  echo "File $FILE exists, mysql is safe!"
else
  echo "File $FILE does not exists, secure mysql"'> /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
  echo mysqladmin -u root password '"'secret'"' >> /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
  echo mysql -u root -p'"'secret'"' -e '"'UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD(\'secret\') WHERE User=\'root\''"' >> /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
  echo mysql -u root -p'"'secret'"' -e '"'DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User=\'root\' AND Host NOT IN (\'localhost\', \'127.0.0.1\', \'::1\')'"' >> /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
  echo mysql -u root -p'"'secret'"' -e '"'DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User=\'\''"' >> /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
  echo mysql -u root -p'"'secret'"' -e '"'DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db=\'test\' OR Db=\'test\_%\''"' >> /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
  echo mysql -u root -p'"'secret'"' -e '"'FLUSH PRIVILEGES'"'>> /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
  echo touch /root/mysqlsecure >> /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
  echo fi >> /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
  chmod +x /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
```

it will only echo the first line" echo mysqladmin -u root password '"'secret'"' >> /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh" the other lines don't appended to the mysqlsec_skript.sh

Could someone help me to correct escape or use a other tool like "sed" that the script would correct created ?

Please excuse my bad english and thanks for the help!

Comment: It may be simpler in a `%post` bit to `wget` the script and then run it, instead of trying to mix the script into the kickstart config. Easier to test that way, too.

Comment: mh yes that could be a simple solution. But then i have to manage two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood all your echo's, but this may be want you want. 
Put exactly what you want to have in the mysqlsec_skript.sh file inside a **here string**, i.e. a multiline string that starts on the line after a "<<'endoffileindicator'", and ends just before a line consisting of only the chosen endoffileindicator.  I used the single char "!" as endoffileindicator.  So the `cat` command reads everything until the line with just "!" (no spaces allowed), and copies it to your destination.

```
cat <<'!' > /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/root/mysqlsecure
if [ -f $FILE ]
then
  echo "File $FILE exists, mysql is safe!"
else
  echo "File $FILE does not exists, secure mysql"
  mysqladmin -u root password 'secret' 
  mysql -u root -p'secret' -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('secret') WHERE User='root'" 
  mysql -u root -p'secret' -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1')" 
  mysql -u root -p'secret' -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User=''" 
  mysql -u root -p'secret' -e "DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\_%'" 
  mysql -u root -p'secret' -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
  touch /root/mysqlsecure 
fi 
!
chmod +x /root/mysqlsec_skript.sh
```

Comment: yeah thanks. never heard " here string"..